# Why can't I add a bridged adapter in Virtual Box?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

I am trying to add a bridged adapter to my [AndoVM](http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/) virtual machine in Virtual Box.

But I can't - when I try to do so, the error message `Invalid settings detected` message appears.

[image]

How can I fix it (add a bridged adapter with my default network connection so that I can access the internet from the Android emulator) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by upgrading to the most recent version of VirtualBox.

Comment: I m using last version 5.0.0 (2015) on a Windows 8.1 host machine but I still have this problema

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the (TestBuilds) version 5.1.x revision 118435 from

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

fixed the issue on my side.